# How to verify onclick jQuery div handler

Tags: jquery, onclick

I'm trying to add a javascript onclick event to an expandable jQuery list tag.

http://screencast.com/t/bbu2fQnqP0rs

My jQuery looks like:

```
jQuery('ul.childpages li.expandable div.expandable-hitarea').click(function() {
    piwiTracker.trackPageView('TreeClick');
    alert("Handler for .click() called.");
});
```

How can I verify whether a click on the hitarea div (heavily nested) will trigger the function?

**Edit** : I added the alert handler above but I'm not getting an alert when I select the div.

By the way, the Piwik documentation to track JS events:

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:piwikTracker.trackPageView('Menu/Freedom');">Freedom page</a>
```

Comment: "_How can I verify whether a click on the hitarea div (heavily nested) will trigger the function?_" - by testing it?

Comment: What do you mean verify? you added a handler, it will happen! why won't it?

Comment: use `console.log()` or `alert` sth within handler.

Comment: I added the alert but it's not working

Comment: I would add the `alert()` or `console.log()` as the first thing to fire off in the click bind just so you know it isn't the following javascript that breaks it.

Answer (score 1):

The following will do the trick:

```
$('ul.childpages li.expandable div.expandable-hitarea').click(function() {
    console.log("Clicked it!");
    piwiTracker.trackPageView('TreeClick');
});
```

You can then right-click in your browser (if you have Firefox, Google Chrome or Safari) and choose Inspect Element. Then choose the "Console" or "Log" option.

---

*IMPORTANT:* When you do not see any logging you should check your element path (the "ul.childpages ..." string). ***You can also check any errors in this log which might break your code.***

---

At last, you can debug it by giving your element a unique ID and only call it with that ID like:

```
$('#uniqueId').click(function() {
   console.log("Clicked it!");
   piwiTracker.trackPageView('TreeClick');
});
```

Comment: I like this better than my answer... you probably need to add a unique ID